# Whitespace if slick-carousel has variableWidth and dynamic container

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I have variable number of cards and also the container is of dynamic dimensions.
So I set `variableWidth: true` and as per requirement `infinite: false`
What I have is below issue where I have to solve.

[image]

I want the first and last slide to stick to edges.

I am using [Jquery Slick Carousel](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

JS Fiddle to quickly check the issue
https://jsfiddle.net/34mjkz38/

Answer (score 1):

Check the code at this merge request, it worked for me. 
https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/pull/2635
He adds a new option called "outerEdgeLimit".